# is there a more elegant way to code this builder?

Tags: java, builder

Here is my snippet:

```
WebClient webClient;
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        webClient = WebClient.builder() //
                .baseUrl(eprBaseUrl) //
                .codecs(codecConfigurer -> {
                    codecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(loggingEncoder);
                }) //
                .build();
    } else {
        webClient = WebClient.builder() //
                .baseUrl(eprBaseUrl) //
                .build();
    }
```

Is there a better/more efficient way to write this block
without condition block (if/else)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the relevant part like this:

```
WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(eprBaseUrl);
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
  webClientBuilder.codecs(codecConfigurer -> {
     codecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(loggingEncoder);
  });
}
WebClient webClient = webClientBuilder.build();
```

Comment: thanks. i think this is the most smart way.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your builder until if block and set only .codecs into if section:

```
    WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder = WebClient.builder();
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        webClientBuilder
                .codecs(codecConfigurer -> {
                    codecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(loggingEncoder);
                });
    }
    webClientBuilder
            .baseUrl(eprBaseUrl)
            .build();
```

Comment: Please note that it's [WebClient.Builder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.Builder.html), not `WebClientBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

*Then* branch differs from *else* by call to one extra `codecs` method. This drives options available:

1. If you want to stay with single expression, check if **`null`** is
   possible to pass to `codecs`. If yes, use conditional expression as
   argument to `codecs`:

   ```
       .codecs(logger.isDebugEnabled() ? /*logging codec*/ : null)
   ```
2. If you are happy without single expression or first option is not
   possible, you still can extract additional part and let common
   parts together:

   ```
       WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder() //
                   .baseUrl(eprBaseUrl);
       if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
         builder.codecs(/*logging codec*/);
       webClient = builder.build();
   ```